# deflate/gzip compression not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, compression, gzip

I have classic shared hosting(apache). In phpinfo() it's both enabled.

> gzip compression enabled

I tried to use this:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Also this:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/css text/html text/xml
</IfModule>
```

But it's not working for me. Response headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 03 Aug 2015 15:29:08 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Mon, 03 Aug 2015 14:28:34 GMT
ETag: "64325f33-1ebd5-51c68fc093cbc"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Expires: Mon, 10 Aug 2015 15:29:08 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/javascript
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

so it's missing `Content-Encoding gzip`. If I run my script using [this](http://checkgzipcompression.com/) it shows me

> It's GZIP Enabled.72.9%
>   Was saved by compressing this page with GZIP.

But in my code it's not working(there's no compression). What should I do/try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that compression is working OK. Server does not respond as expected because, [according RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.3), you need to specify that you want to have compressed response by adding Accept-Encoding header with one of supported [content-codings](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.5) to your request.

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Comment: well I have got there this: Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, isn't it enough?

Comment: Will you please show whole request headers? Or may be there is publicly available address where I can take a look?

Comment: There is also [gzipWTF](http://gzipwtf.com/) project which can show what parts of your project are covered with compression

Comment: I accepted your answer though it hasn't helped me. Problem was with my internet provider, something with proxy was blocking it(solution - using https)